# JS code snippet from a book

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var person = { name: "Nicholas" };
var people = [{ name: "Nicholas" }];
var morePeople = [person];

alert(people.indexOf(person)); //-1
alert(morePeople.indexOf(person)); //0
```

I can't figure out why first alert gives -1 (not found) when people is an array and contains `{ name: "Nicholas" }`

Comment: Because two different object *"instances"* are never equal to each other.

Comment: You created two different objects. They just happen to share the same string value, but not the same value themselves.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because while both objects contain the same information, they aren't the same object. For example:

```
var nick = { name: 'Nick' };
var nick2 = { name: 'Nick' };
console.log(nick === nick2); // false
console.log(nick === nick); // true
```

This is true because Javascript doesn't do per-property comparisons between objects to determine equality. It only checks "*is this literally the exact same object as the other one?*" If, and only if, that is true will you get a true result when comparing two objects.

`.indexOf` uses such comparisons to determine if any object or value is in an array.